# Symfony 4 include another project from different directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

So, I have an application that consists of 5 different projects.

Each of the projects is a new Symfony 4 project, since I need to host them on separate domains.

My structure is like this:
Admin project: /var/www/html/admin
Client project: /var/www/html/client
Owners project: /var/www/html/owners

Each of the project has its own symfony skelet (src,public,config,bundles,public, etc...)

I know this can be done through bundle, but, what I want to do is to create a new Symfony project (Common) and use it accross all the others. Since ill be having same entities and same common services through projects, I need to include it in each of them.

Is there a way to include this Common project into all others and use services/entities from there?

Comment: You seem to be describing a Symfony bundle, so yes.

Comment: @Cerad I am describing another project. One is at /var/www/admin and the common should be at /var/www/common

Comment: Cerad is right. Put the common stuff in a bundle. You can use a monolith if you want to, but if you have the time decouple it.

Comment: Perhaps you could define what a "project" is and how 5 of them relates to "an applications"?

Comment: It's worth reading Symfony's documentation to get a full picture of what's possible - [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html) may be a good starting point for you.

Comment: I edited the question, please see now if you understand what I need

Comment: so @DarraghEnright answered your question. look at the link above: u can put your common parts: enteties etc into a vendor-bundle and include it everywhere in your project via composer.

Comment: @myxaxa yep, think thats what I need, thanks!

Comment: This question is probably too broad for stackoverflow but I'd strongly recommend you going for a monolith and not only introduce a common bundle but merge those applications together. It'll save you a lot of hustle with maintenance, deployments etc. in the long run. You can always configure your webserver to meet your local/remote/domain-restriction requirements and further restrict symfony's routes by host plus add according security-configuration/-voters to keep everything secure. Don't be shy ... go for the monolith/monorepo - thank me later :)