# Symfony Code Maintainability Across Separate Projects On Separate Domains

Tags: symfony, virtualhost, symfony4

I have two separate projects in Symfony 4. The first project will be used by customers, while the second project will be used by employees. Both projects use the same entities, repositories, namespaces, configurations and so on. The only difference between the projects is the controllers and their content. Some restrictions about the separate projects:

**Domain Public (Used by customers)**

- Public server, so anyone can connect to this server.
- Sometimes up and running (online). Other times it's down and not running (offline) causing users to see a "This site can't be reached" error on Google Chrome as example.
- Requires no client certificate

**Domain Private (Used by employees)**

- Can only be accessed by the local network.
- Always up and running (online)
- Requires client certificate

As you can see, the public domain has some strange requirements, these are for maximum security. To host both the projects on the same server I use virtual hosts on Apache and configured these correctly.

Now I have the following problem: Any chances which are not made inside a controller, I have to manually copy and paste in the second project as well. So I want both domains, both websites, to share the same resources, so I have to only edit them at one place. How could I achieve this? I imagine two solutions:

- Merge the two projects together into one so they share the same resources. That way they would share the same entities and so on, and I could make a separate directory for each domain in the default controller directory. But I don't think this is possible with my restrictions.
- So in my web root directory, I have two separate directories for each project. I could make a third directory which contains all the shared files (so basically every file except for the controllers). But how can I reference to the shared files like my custom entities, but also the composer.json since both projects will use the exact same dependencies.

If someone could just give me some advice on how to tackle this problem, that would help a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651571/symfony-4-include-another-project-from-different-directory

Comment: This question is probably too broad for stackoverflow but I'd strongly recommend you going for a monolith and merge those two applications together. It'll save you a lot of hustle with maintenance, deployments etc. in the long run. You can always configure your webserver to meet your local/remote/domain-restriction requirements and further restrict symfony's routes by host plus add according security-configuration/-voters to keep everything _secure_. Don't be shy ... go for the monolith/monorepo. Thank me later :)

Comment: Considering how similar your projects are, you should probably have one single codebase and use environment variables, server variables and/or configuration files to force the behavior of the public vs private domains.

Comment: @NicolasB This is the approach we eventually settled with. We've decided to merge the two projects together, and add additional checks on basically everything to force the behaviour we desire.